# Row with schema returns null for row.schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know that you would expect code for this, but the code looks fine and I am unable to understand what's going wrong though. I would explain the problem and let's see if you could tell me if I am missing something obvious.

I have written an implicit class for `Row`, a function in which uses the `row.schema` to get the schema. What's funny though that `row.schema` always returns `null` in the implicit class whether the row object has a schema or not, whereas the same returns the actual schema, in the class containing the unit test (I use `FlatSpec with Matchers` for unit testing). This is how the row is constructed in the unit test.

```
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("col1", StringType) ::
  StructField("col2", DoubleType) ::
  StructField("col3", IntegerType) ::
  Nil)
val values = Array("value1", 1.0, 1)
val row: Row = new GenericRowWithSchema(values, schema)
```

I check the source in the Spark code base and this is how the `schema` function is implemented.

```
def schema: StructType = null
```

which confused me even further. Any pointers?

**Edit:** I should have known no code doesn't really help. So here's the code. Check the `getAsOpt[T](i)` ([here](https://github.com/aa8y/spark/blob/getAsOpt/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala#L323)) and `getAsOpt[T](fieldName)` ([here](https://github.com/aa8y/spark/blob/getAsOpt/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala#L346)) functions in [this code](https://github.com/aa8y/spark/blob/getAsOpt/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala) for `Row` and the corresponding tests [here](https://github.com/aa8y/spark/blob/getAsOpt/sql/catalyst/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RowTest.scala).

Here's how the ones which fail, fail,

```
[info] - getAsOpt[T]() can get values using field names. *** FAILED *** (8 milliseconds)
[info]   None was not equal to Some("value1") (RowTest.scala:85)
...
[info] - getAsOpt[T] retrieves an Optional value if the fieldName exists  else returns None *** FAILED *** (1 millisecond)
[info]   None was not equal to Some("value1") (RowTest.scala:91)
...
[info] - getAsOpt[T] retrieves an Optional value if class cast is successful else returns None *** FAILED *** (0 milliseconds)
[info]   None was not equal to Some("value1") (RowTest.scala:97)
```

Comment: [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would in place here. It is hard to understand what is the problem not to mention reproduce it.

Comment: @zero323 Added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what exactly is the problem here so I'll address only the second part. `schema` definition in the `GenericRowWithSchema` [is overridden](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d83c2f9f0b08d6d5d369d9fae04cdb15448e7f0d/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/rows.scala#L207) as follows:

```
class GenericRowWithSchema(values: Array[Any], override val schema: StructType)
```

To illustrate what is going on consider following example

```
trait Foobar {
  def foo: Integer = null
}

class Foo(override val foo: Integer) extends Foobar
class Bar extends Foobar

new Foo(1).foo != null
// Boolean = true
new Bar().foo == null
// Boolean = true
```

Comment: Code has been added. Hope this clarifies it more.